# For Each Loop through DataGridViewColumn Headers

Tags: vb.net, string, foreach, indexof

I have a `DataGridView` called `DataGridViewHistorical` that has columns for 2012 to 1900.  I am trying to loop through the column headers and use the year to find a specific date in a string.  So in the example below I would be looking for `2012-01-03, 2011-01-03, 2010-01-03 ... 1900-01-03.`

```
For Each columnYear As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewHistorical.Columns
  MessageBox.Show(strBuffer.IndexOf(columnYear & "-01-03"))
Next
```

When I run this code I get error "Operator '&' is not defined for types `'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' and 'String'."`

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `HeaderText` property of the `DataGridViewColumn`:

```
MessageBox.Show(strBuffer.IndexOf(columnYear.HeaderText & "-01-03"))
```

Comment: That doesn't give me an error but nothing happens when I debug.

Comment: @nordeen1 Define "nothing happens".  No MessageBox means you have no columns.

Comment: @nordeen1 When you debug, what happens when you get to the For-Each loop?

Comment: This is how I add my columns this may have something to do with my problem.        With Me
                lr = Now.Year - 1901
                For i = 1 To lr
                column = New DataColumn
                column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
                    column.ColumnName = Now.Year - i
                    dt.Columns.Add(column)
                Next i
            End With

Comment: what exactly do you mean "what happens when you get to the For-Each loop?"

Comment: @nordeen1 You still didn't answer the question of what happens when you get to the For-Each loop when you step through with the debugger.  Also, where in your code are you doing this looping?

Comment: @nordeen1 I'm reacting to your statement "nothing happens when I debug".  Debugging implies you are stepping through each line of code line by line.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to step through vb in debugger.  I cam from VBA in Excel and I could step through that easily but I've never been able to step through in VB.  Sorry for my inexperience.  Also, which looping are you referring to?

Comment: What I am doing when I debug is pressing the Start Debugging button which opens my project.  I then click the button that calls my code and my DataGridView loads but no message box opens.

Comment: @nordeen1 I was referring to the columnYear loop.  Click on that line in your code, press F9, run your program, when it stops there, press F8 to step into the code line by line.  You can examine the values of the variables while the program is paused at that moment.

Comment: Okay I put a breakpoint at my    For Each columnYear    line of code.  When I press F8 it goes past the    MessageBox    line and the    Next    line and goes straight to the    dt.Rows.Add(dr)    line.  I don't see how to examine the values of the variables.  Which variables do you mean?

Comment: if I do QuickWatch on the MessageBox.Show it says "Expression does not produce a value"

Comment: @nordeen1 I think we've reached the end here.  The question was about the error message and that got resolved.  For the missing column headers, try posting a new question with more details.  Try to post the code that can duplicate the issue.