# Get the Collection of DataGridView Header

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

[image: My Running DataGridView]

I have a **DataGridView** and a **Combobox** (for sorting), What I want is to get the collection of **DataGridView Header** when I run the application and make it a **DataSource** of my **Combobox**.

Answer (score 2):

I got it through intensive researching..

```
Dim ch As New List(Of String)
For Each header As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    ch.Add(header.HeaderText)
Next

cbSort.DataSource = ch
```

I create a variable as an string array, then loop through the column of my `DatagridView` and get each column header and assign it to my array variable.
Then I make it as `DataSource` of my **Combobox**.

Some reference that i have seen and got an idea:

[List String Array Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/390048/dynamic-string-array-in-vb-net)

[DataGridView Header Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/198794/how-to-get-columns-name-of-datagridview-at-run-tim)

[Other Useful Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631357/for-each-loop-through-datagridviewcolumn-headers)